# Laravel 4 - list posts collection only with associated comments

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to display a list of posts that have NO comments associated with them.  In other words, in my one-to-many relationship, if there are children, the post shouldn't display.

Besides doing this with raw query, is there an easy way to do this eloquently?

Model - Post.php

```
  public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
```

Model - Comment.php

```
 public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
```

Controller - PostController.php

```
public function unanswered()
{

    $posts = Post::with('comments')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);


    return View::make('unanswered')->with('posts',$posts);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch models that either have, or not, given relation, you need to use `has` method.

Depending on what you want to achieve use plain `has('relation')` or pass additional parameters:

```
$posts = Post::has('comments', '<', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I absolutely should have known this :-)

Answer (score 1):

with('comments') is to eager load

what you need is actually a join on with a where.